# Angularjs form validation on Form Submission

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS. I have developed a simple Angular UI Modal form and I am trying to validate the form on form submission i.e. when end user click the submit button. I followed an video lecture that uses a Angular directive to validate the fields that places 'has-error' class on the parent element. please the images for the clarification.

### Angular Form

[image]

### Error Directive

[image]

### HTML Template

[image]

I want the messages Full Name is required , A valid email is required should only be displayed when either Save button is clicked or the input controls fires up the blur event.
please guide what I am missing here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
E-mail:
<input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required="" />

<div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">A valid email.is required</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I would approve your suggestion as an answer. Here I would like to share that I am experiencing a weird behavior of my application which I have understood a bit. Its the blur event in the Error directive for toggling has-error class. There comes a situation when I enter something move and next input, comes back to first one and make it empty then the validation shows up but 'has-error's class is only added when i move to next control i.e. until blur event is fire.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `ng-if` in your error message `span` tags

```
ng-if="(employeeForm.fullName.$isDirty || employeeForm.$submitted) && <rest of your validation>"
```

This will then eval to true if the field has been entered by the user OR the form has been submitted.